# walking through a directory and appending to a dictionary if specific order

Tags: python

I'm attempting to walk through a directory containing over 650+ directories where each directory has 3 subdirectories, which then contain `.png` files. So that I have something that resembles:

```
MAIN
└───folder_01
|   └─subfolder_01
|   | └─12.png
|   └─subfolder_02
|   | └─... .png
|   └─subfolder_03
|     └─cm_12.png   
│
└───folder_02
|   └─subfolder_01
|   | └─34.png
|   └─subfolder_02
|   | └─... .png
|   └─subfolder_03
|     └─cm_34.png   
│
...
```

What I'm attempting to do is the extract the path from the `.png` in `subfolder_01` and `subfolder_03`. Both those folders contain a single `.png` image and the file in `subfolder_03` has the same name as the file in `subfolder_01` with the addition of the prefix `cm_`.

I would like to store the paths in a dictionary where the key is the image  name (without the extension) and the value is a tuple where the first entry is the path of the image found in  `subfolder_01` and the second entry would be the path to the image found in `subfolder_03`, so that I have something like:

```
my_dict = {image 12 name: (path to 12.png, path to cm_12.png,
           image 34 name: (path to 34.png, path to cm_34.png),
           ...}
```

to further complicate matters the image files are a 64 length hash. I have some code below, but I ran into a problem because it seems to go to `subfolder_03` and pick out that image before going to `subfolder_01`. I've attempted to reverse the order of my `if` statement which resolves the problem but I'm hoping to find a solution that is a little more general, that is doesn't really depend on the order of the `if` statement.

For completeness the code:

```
 def get_data(loc: str) -> Dict[str, Directories]:
    """
    Looks through the given directory and returns a dictionary where the
    key is the file name and the values are the locations of the training
    image and the mask
    """
    im_paths = []
    im_imMask = {}

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(loc):
        # mask_paths = []
        im_combined = ""
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".png"):
                im_path = root + "/{}".format(file)
                im_paths.append(im_path)
                # print(root)
                if os.path.basename(root) == "images":
                    key = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
                    im_loc = root + "/{}".format(file)
                elif os.path.basename(root) == "combined":
                    im_combined = root + "/{}".format(file)
                    # mask_paths.append(root + "/{}".format(file))
            im_imMask[key] = (im_loc, im_combined) 

    return im_imMask
```

Comment: You want to walk the folders is a specific order?

Comment: The documentation for [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) explains that the order is arbitrary (up to your OS) but also explains how to use `topdown` mode and mutating `dirnames` to "impose a specific order of visiting".

Comment: If the directories' structure is exactly like what you show, I don't think you need to walk through it. Why cannot you list directories by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is get an entry like this by the time you're done:

```
image 12 name: (path to 12.png, path to cm_12.png)
```

… no matter which order you visit the two files.

This will be easier if you're willing to have a list of the two files instead of a tuple. Then you can do something like:

```
key = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
if filename.startswith('cm_'):
    key = key[3:]
    d.setdefault(key, [None, None])[1] = path
else:
    d.setdefault(key, [None, None])[0] = path
```

The `setdefault` will make sure that whichever file you find earlier will create a `[None, None]` before replacing the first or second element, but whichever one you find later will operate on the already-created pair.

---

It sounds like you want to wrap up that `setdefault` so you don't have to repeat yourself. You could refactor it into a function:

```
def storename(key, idx):
    d.setdefault(key, [None, None])[idx] = path
if filename.startswith('cm_'):
    storename(key[3:], 1)
else:
    storename(key, 0)
```

Or you could store the values in variables:

```
cm = filename.startswith('cm_')
if cm:
    key = [3:]
d.setdefault(key, [None, None])[cm] = path
```

(This relies on the fact that `True` and `False` are the same as `1` and `0`. If that seems mysterious to you, change it to `cm = 1 if filename.startswith('cm_') else 0`.)

Or you could combine the two.

Comment: You're correct that I don't really care which gets seen first as long as the output is as descriped. At the moment I applied the solution under both `if os.path.basename(root) == "images":` and `elif os.path.basename(root) == "combined"` is there a way to simply have it apply this solution in one area or does it necessarily need to be contained in both the `if` and `elif` conditions?

Comment: @Lukasz I've edited the answer to explain what I think you want to do there.